# Racket: can we import struct only from other module?

Tags: racket

file `lib.rkt`:

```lisp
#lang typed/racket
(provide 
    distance
    pt-to-string
    (struct-out pt))

(struct pt ([x : Real] [y : Real]))

(: pt-to-string (-> pt String))
(define (pt-to-string p) (string-append "struct pt: x=" (number->string (pt-x p)) ", y=" (number->string (pt-y p)) "."))

(: distance (-> pt pt Real))
(define (distance p1 p2)
  (sqrt (+ (sqr (- (pt-x p2) (pt-x p1)))
           (sqr (- (pt-y p2) (pt-y p1))))))
```

file `main.rkt`:

```lisp
#lang typed/racket
(require
  ; import struct pt only, include pt, pt-x and pt-y
  (only-in "./lib.rkt" pt pt-x pt-y))

(define p (pt -1 1))
(displayln (pt-x p))
```

I want to import struct pt only ,which include `pt` `pt-x` and `pt-y`, but not import all other helper function such as `distance` and `pt-to-string`.

Is there anything corresponding to `(provide (struct-out ...))` ?

Comment: Are you wondering whether there is a convenient "short form" instead of enumerating what you want, like, say, "struct-in"? I think the information that the exports are related to a struct does not exist at that point.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, I need something like "struct-in".

Comment: If the importing module can tell that a bunch of names belong to a particular struct definition that means that the providing module can never change the implementation.  That's bad.